# Add dropdown component to a column of data table

Tags: angular, primeng

I use PrimeNG and Angular 2 for building a web application displaying a data table. This works well so far, however I want to have a dropdown component inside a data cell, that means template-wise that p-column shall include another p-dropdown element as follows:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="dataColumns" [(selection)]="selectedInputColumns">
        <header>Specify Input Columns</header>
        <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
        <p-column field="label" header="Column Name"></p-column>\n\
        <p-column header="Column Type">
           <p-dropdown [options]="dataColumns" [(ngModel)]="selectedDmuColumn"></p-dropdown> 
        </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

The respective column does not display anything, even if I only put a simple text instead of the dropdown, it does not show up.

Do I miss anything or is it simply note foreseen to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `<template>` beneath the p-column, like this,
per PrimeNg datatable documentation:

> A template inside a column must be decorated with pTemplate directive
>   along with the type property to indicate where the template belongs
>   to. Possible values are "header", "body" and "footer".

```
<p-column header="Column Type">
    <template pTemplate type="header">
       <p-dropdown [options]="dataColumns" [(ngModel)]="selectedDmuColumn"></p-dropdown> 
    </template>
</p-column>
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it!